# Global scope inside if/else for a running median

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, global, scoping

I'm implementing a running median algorithm in Python using two heaps. However, the heaps don't grow in size even if I push to them...

I suspect it's something to do with the scoping inside `if/else` statements.
I don't really understand how to fix this.

```py
import os
import numpy
import functools
import heapq
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop 


@functools.total_ordering
class ReverseCompare(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, ReverseCompare) and self.obj == other.obj
    def __le__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, ReverseCompare) and self.obj >= other.obj
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.obj)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.obj)


curMedian = 0
leftHeap = map(ReverseCompare, [])
rightHeap = []
heapq.heapify(rightHeap)
heapq.heapify(leftHeap)

def runningMed(n):
    #importing the global variables
    global curMedian 
    global leftHeap
    global rightHeap
    #The first time
    if (curMedian == 0):
        curMedian = n
        return curMedian

    #the second +... time
    # print "debug"
    # print rightHeap
    # print leftHeap
    # heapq.heappush(leftHeap, 3)
    # heapq.heappush(rightHeap, 3)
    # print rightHeap

    print "length of heaps"
    print len(rightHeap)
    print len(leftHeap)

    if (len(rightHeap) > len(leftHeap) + 2):
        print "Debug long right heap"

        if(n >= curMedian):
            heapq.heappush(leftHeap, curMedian)
            curMedian = heapq.heappop(rightHeap)
            heappop.heappush(rightHeap, n)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(leftHeap, n)

    elif (len(leftHeap) > len(rightHeap) + 2):
        print "Debug long"
        if(n <= curMedian):
            heapq.heappush(rightHeap, curMedian)
            curMedian = heapq.heappop(leftHeap)
            heappop.heappush(leftHeap, n)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(rightHeap,n)

    else:
        print "Debug curMedian"
        print n
        print curMedian
        if (n > curMedian):
            heapq.heappush(rightHeap, n)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(leftHeap,n)

    #TReturn the median:

    if (len(leftHeap) == len(rightHeap)):
        return curMedian
    elif (len(leftHeap) > len(rightHeap)):
        return (heapq.heappop(leftHeap) + curMedian)/2
    else:
        return (heapq.heappop(rightHeap) + curMedian)/2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #TODO: Input/output names must be changed
    inputFile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')

    for line in inputFile:
        num = int(line.rstrip('\n'))
        med = runningMed(num)
        outputFile.write(str(med) + '\n')

    inputFile.close()
    outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Note that `leftHeap = map(ReverseCompare, [])` has the same result as `leftHeap = []`.  Also note that `ReverseCompare` is used nowhere else in your code.

Comment: There is a lot of commented out code and superfluous print statements in your code.  Also there is an unused `ReverseCompare` class.  I suggest editing your question to a more manageable size cutting out the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has nothing to do with scope. The heaps don't grow because you pop newly added elements right off at the end:

```
    return (heapq.heappop(leftHeap) + curMedian)/2
else:
    return (heapq.heappop(rightHeap) + curMedian)/2
```

Just look at the max/min element without popping it off:

```
    return (leftHeap[0] + curMedian)/2
else:
    return (rightHeap[0] + curMedian)/2
```

---

My own version I mentioned in the comments:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

left, right = [], []
def runmed(n):
    global left, right
    if len(left) <= len(right):
        heappush(left, -n)
    else:
        heappush(right, n)
    if right and -left[0] > right[0]:
        heappush(left, -heappop(right))
        heappush(right, -heappop(left))
    if len(left) > len(right):
        return -left[0]
    return (right[0] - left[0]) / 2.0
```

- `left` is a max-heap of the smaller half of the numbers and contains those numbers negated to get the max-heap functionality.
- `right` is a min-heap of the larger half of the numbers.
- `left` is always the same size as `right`, or one larger.

Test code:

```
import random
numbers = []
for _ in range(15):
    n = random.randrange(100)
    numbers.append(n)
    print '{:<4} is median of {}'.format(runmed(n), sorted(numbers))
```

Output:

```
38   is median of [38]
27.5 is median of [17, 38]
38   is median of [17, 38, 79]
27.5 is median of [4, 17, 38, 79]
17   is median of [4, 12, 17, 38, 79]
27.5 is median of [4, 12, 17, 38, 63, 79]
38   is median of [4, 12, 17, 38, 63, 69, 79]
35.0 is median of [4, 12, 17, 32, 38, 63, 69, 79]
38   is median of [4, 12, 17, 32, 38, 39, 63, 69, 79]
38.5 is median of [4, 12, 17, 32, 38, 39, 63, 69, 79, 82]
39   is median of [4, 12, 17, 32, 38, 39, 47, 63, 69, 79, 82]
38.5 is median of [4, 12, 17, 21, 32, 38, 39, 47, 63, 69, 79, 82]
38   is median of [4, 12, 17, 21, 25, 32, 38, 39, 47, 63, 69, 79, 82]
35.0 is median of [4, 12, 14, 17, 21, 25, 32, 38, 39, 47, 63, 69, 79, 82]
38   is median of [4, 12, 14, 17, 21, 25, 32, 38, 39, 47, 62, 63, 69, 79, 82]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this was the problem

Comment: @JennyLian You're welcome. Can you accept the answer then? Cool problem, btw, I also coded it myself for fun.

Comment: I'm not sure if I accepted it right... btw, how did you do the max heap portion? (the numbers smaller than median). I cannot find max heap in python so I had to apply -1 to all the numbers go on it.

Comment: @JennyLian I added my version to my answer now so you can see it. I did the max heap by negating the numbers as well, seemed easiest. Alternatively, you could wrap the number like you originally tried with your ReverseCompare. And there are undocumented functions like `heapq._heapify_max`, but there's just a combined pushpop for max.

Answer (score 0):

Python global scope can be kind of finicky.  Life might be easier if you wrap this in a class where each instance has their own leftHeap, rightHeap, and curMedian.